# select joined columns from joined tables using concat() like '%%'

Tags: c#, mysql

I was wondering if I could select values from joined tables

my tables are as following:

```
mysql> desc tblvitsign;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| vitsignid | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| bp        | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bpstat    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hr        | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hrstat    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rr        | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rrstat    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| temp      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tempstat  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| weight    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| height    | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bmi       | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| bmistatus | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| patientid | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| date      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc tblpatient;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| patientid    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| lastname     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| firstname    | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| middlename   | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender       | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| birthday     | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age          | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

i joined them like so:

> mysql> select a.lastname, a.firstname, a.middlename, b.bp, b.bpstat, b.hr, b.hrstat, b.rr, b.rrstat, b.temp, b.tempstat,
>   b.weight, b.height, b.bmi, b.bmistatus from tblpatient a left join
>   tblvitsign b on a.patientid = b.patientid;

```
+----------+-------------+------------+--------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+------+----------+--------+--------+-------+-----------+
| lastname | firstname   | middlename | bp     | bpstat | hr   | hrstat | rr   | rrstat | temp | tempstat | weight | height | bmi   | bmistatus |
+----------+-------------+------------+--------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+------+----------+--------+--------+-------+-----------+
| Smith    | Mark        | Richards   | 120/80 | Normal | 75   | Normal | 15   | Normal | 37   | Normal   | 56     | 1.7    | 19.38 | Normal    |
+----------+-------------+------------+--------+--------+------+--------+------+--------+------+----------+--------+--------+-------+-----------+
```

I am making a query for my search bar and I used this query using concat and like functions but it returns an empty set

> mysql> select a.lastname, a.firstname, a.middlename, b.bp, b.bpstat,
>   b.hr, b.hrstat, b.rr, b.rrstat, b.temp, b.tempstat, b.weight,
>   b.height, b.bmi, b.bmistatus from tblpatient a left join tblvitsign b
>   on a.patientid = b.patientid where concat('a.lastname', 'a.firstname',
>   'a.middlename', 'b.bp', 'b.bpstat', 'b.hr', 'b.hrstat', 'b.rr',
>   'b.rrstat', 'b.temp', 'b.tempstat', 'b.weight', 'b.height', 'b.bmi',
>   'b.bmistatus') like '%ma%';
>    **Empty set (0.14 sec)**

is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How about if you don't use `'` for pointing field names like `concat(a.lastname, a.firstname, a.middlename, b.bp...` ?

Comment: `'a.lastname'` means **literally** that string, not the column name.

Comment: Also, please show your C# code - since I am worried your code may be open to SQL Injection.